# jquery bootstrap modal all input text

Tags: jquery, input, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this problem; 
look http://jsfiddle.net/SLnZR/

I want to get all my text input val from my modal form. When I clicked "Submit" my

```
$('#ModalProdotti').find('input:text').each(function()
```

result 0. Thank's a lot.
Aesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Aesis this is because you're using a normal javascript array. If you change

```
myarray = new array() to myarray = {};
```

the code will work. This is because arrays in javascript expect numeric indexes and you were giving it string names for its members. It doesn't throw an error because it's javascript but it jSON.stringify doesn't work with it. http://www.jsfiddle.net/7LzjX